# Regexp to check if string contains at least one '.'

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the most simple way to checks if a string contains at least one '.' with a regex?

```
'myfile.html' = true
'anotherfilebutnodot' = false
```

Comment: Why not try out yourself? http://www.regexpal.com

Comment: I can think of a 2-character regular expression that would answer that for you, but the answer is so simple its either a homework question or you need to first read up on a basic regex tutorial.

Comment: to me regexp is extremely difficult and I find it really hard to understand the logics - that's why I reached out for help. sorry!

Comment: Have you looked at the [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?  Documentation is your friend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a fixed "pattern" like a single `.` character, regexes are MASSIVE overkill.

```
var mystr = 'Hello. There.';

if (mystr.indexOf('.') == -1) {
   alert("No period found");
}
```

Comment: you are right, I was snowed in on the whole regex thing, didn't realize there were other options too! thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to escape the . you can do that by using a slash `\`.

So your regex will be: `\.`

Answer (score 1):

Marc B is quite right; here's that solution bundled into a boolean function:

```
function containsDot(myFile){
    return myFile.indexOf('.') != -1;
}
```